# access k8s apis from outside

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to access k8s api resources. my cluster is 1node cluster. kube-api server is listening on 8080 and 6443 port. curl localhost:8080/api/v1 inside node is working. if i hit :8080, its not working because some other service (eureka) is running on this port. this leaves me option to access :6443 . in order to do make api accessible, there are 2 ways.

1- create service for kube-api with some specific port which will target 6443. For that ca.crt , key , token etc are required. How to create and configure such things so that i will be able to access api.

2- make change in waeve (weave is available as service in k8s setup) so that my server can access k8s apis.

anyone of option is fine with me. any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

> my cluster is 1node cluster

One of [those words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cluster#Noun) does not mean what you think it does. If you haven't already encountered it, you will eventually discover that the memory and CPU pressure of attempting to run all the components of a kubernetes *cluster* on a single Node will cause memory exhaustion, and then lots of things won't work right with some pretty horrible error messages.

I can deeply appreciate wanting to start simple, but you will be much happier with a 3 machine cluster than trying to squeeze everything into a single machine. Not to mention the fact that only having a single machine won't surface any networking misconfigurations, which can be a *separate* frustration when you think everything is working correctly and only then go to scale your cluster up to more Nodes.

> some other service (eureka) is running on this port.

Well, at the very real risk of stating the obvious: why not move one of those two services to listen on a separate port from one another? Many cluster provisioning tools (I love [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray#readme)) have a [configuration option](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/6c220e4e/roles/kubespray-defaults/defaults/main.yaml#L127) that allows one to very easily adjust the insecure port used by the apiserver to be a port of your choosing. It can even be a privileged port (that is: less than 1024) because `docker` runs as `root` and thus can `--publish` a port using any number it likes.

If having the `:8080` is so important to both pieces of software that it would be prohibitively costly to relocate the port, then consider binding the "eureka" software to the machine's IP and bind the kubernetes apiserver's insecure port to 127.0.0.1 (which is certainly the *intent*, anyway). If "eureka" is also running in `docker`, you can change its `--publish` to include an IP address on the "left hand side" to very cheaply do what I said: `--publish ${the_ip}:8080:8080` (or whatever). If it is not using docker, there is still a pretty good chance that the software will accept a "bind address" or "bind host" through which you can enter the ip address, versus "0.0.0.0".

> 1- create service for kube-api with some specific port which will target 6443. For that ca.crt , key , token etc are required. How to create and configure such things so that i will be able to access api.

Every Pod running in your cluster has the option of declaring a `serviceAccountName`, which by default is `default`, and the effect of having a `serviceAccountName` is that every container in the Pod has access to those components you mentioned: the CA certificate and a JWT credential that enables the Pod to invoke the kubernetes API (which from within the cluster one can always access via: the kubernetes `Service` IP, the environment variable `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST`, or the hostname `https://kubernetes` -- assuming you are using kube-dns). Those serviceAccount credentials are automatically projected into the container at `/var/run/secret/kubernetes.io` without requiring that your Pod declare those `volumeMount`s explicitly.

So, if your concern is that one must have credentials from *within* the cluster, that concern can go away pretty quickly. If your concern is access from *outside* the cluster, there are a lot of ways to address that concern which don't directly involve creating all 3 parts of that equation.

Comment: my objective is to access api from outside (some other server). i noticed curl <public_ip>:6443 is accessible . same files i am referring in my prometheus.yml but is ending up with below logs.

Apr  5 05:10:19 ip-172-30-0-11 prometheus: level=error ts=2018-04-05T05:10:19.329246964Z caller=main.go:221 component=k8s_client_runtime err="github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:354: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://13.54.234.241:6443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate is valid for 172.31.6.182, 10.96.12.1, not 13.57.251.241"

Comment: _509: certificate is valid for 172.31.6.182, 10.96.12.1, not 13.57.251.24_ I don't know how prometheus obtained that IP address, but as you can see, the certificate doesn't have a SAN entry for that IP and thus the request is terminated. You can either fix the SAN for the cert, or turn on [insecure_skip_verify](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Ctls_config%3E) for the kubernetes scrape definitions.